# Paypal Giving Error on Magento Cart - 10486 and 11084

Tags: checkout, cart, error, paypal

When my custumers try to buy on my store, the choose Paypal, are redirected to Paypal, insert their card, but after that, they are redirected back to my store cart with these errors:

> This transaction couldn't be completed. Please redirect your customer
>   to PayPal (#10486: This transaction couldn't be completed).
>
> PayPal gateway denied the request. User does not have a good funding
>   source with which to pay (#11084: User does not have a good funding
>   source with which to pay).

Shouldn't this error be presented direct on Paypal?

Check the [Print Screen](https://7atshw.dm2301.livefilestore.com/y2pC1z-5pSl1FEAO-GGHHIJPMAK4vfDuZcf9l0YhKvdd-C_oobCTEGSubLlihWBqmb2UCzdwas1BoDV-0gqpyl2SbF2jPNXUwZh6z1tlGlR7xXNP9W1Zf3gLAHJOGJlCLAgE7psvF81At6zrps56rBrcw/paypal10486-magento.jpg?psid=1).

It's a production store, on a public domain with https.

On paypal support they say that it can be redirect again to Paypal, but Magento is not doing it:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/

Comment: Please give us some more information: Do you use PayPal locally, on dev server (maybe IP/password protected) or on a public domain? Do you use https?

Comment: It's a public domain with https.